# How do I use scipy.ndimage.gaussian_filter1d on an arbitrary axis?

Tags: gdal, numpy

I have a GDAL raster that looks like this:
[image: Unfiltered raster of priority values]

And I would really like to blur this raster along an *arbitrary* transect.

I see that [scipy.ndimage](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/ndimage.html) has a gaussian filter that allows me to blur the raster along a given axis, as long as the axis is valid given the raster's numpy matrix.  Doing so with the default axis of `-1` (and `sigma=2`) looks like this:

[image: Same raster with 1-dimensional gaussian filtering]

This raster is **pretty close** to what I'm looking for, I'd just really like to have this filtering not strictly happen along the horizontal axis, if that's possible.

So my questions are thus:

- Is it possible to filter the matrix along an arbitrary axis, such as an axis that is not necessarily along the vertical or horizontal?
- Is it possible to do so just with Numpy/Scipy and GDAL?

Comment: Why not just convolve the image with an appropriate kernel?  E.g., a 5 x 5 kernel equal to the diagonal matrix [.067, .242, .382, .242, .067] will blur along a 45 degree axis.

Comment: That could totally work!  Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: example please?  I fail to see how it helps